# Create a SQL Query to import data from Excel in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, visual-studio

I've created a database in SQL Server 2014 and I've also made an user interface for it in Visual Studio(the database is conected to my C# project in Visual Studio). 
But I would also want to know if you can write a SQL Query so that, when I press a button(from my C# project) to upload an Excel file from a specific directory directly in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sql bulk insert?

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/